# List all properties for an object - Object 1 at undefined:1

Tags: javascript, cordova

In JavaScript I have this function, the `result` argument is passed in by a SCANQR Code (using PhoneGap) Iam debugging using Eclipse on Android.

I have difficulties in understanding the type and properties for object `result`.

I am posting here the code together with the result of console.

I am puzzled with

```
object at undefined:1
```

and

```
 0 at undefined:1
```

Could you help me to figured out what these messages means and helping to understand the  structure of this object? Is it an array?

```
onQrCodeScan: function(result) {
    console.log("result: " + result);

    var eventTitle = result.SUMMARY;
    var dateTimeStart = result.DTSTART;
    var dateTimeEnd = result.DTEND;
    var location = result.LOCATION;
    var description = result.DESCRIPTION;

    console.log('RESULT IF OF TYPE: ' + typeof(result));

    for (var key in result) {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log('PROPERTY:    '+ key);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): result: BEGIN:VEVENT
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): SUMMARY:my title event
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): DTSTART:20130307T183200Z
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): DTEND:20130307T193200Z
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): LOCATION:london
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): DESCRIPTION:my title event
    03-06 14:31:21.726: I/Web Console(17775): END:VEVENT,QR at undefined:1

    03-06 14:31:21.742: I/Web Console(17775): RESULT IF OF TYPE: object at undefined:1
    03-06 14:31:21.757: I/Web Console(17775): PROPERTY:    0 at undefined:1
    03-06 14:31:21.765: I/Web Console(17775): PROPERTY:    1 at undefined:1
```

I debug using Eclipse on Android.

Comment: Is `result` an `array`? because, `for in` loop doesn't work properly with arrays, it works with `objects`.

Comment: Probably it couldn't create a source map, so instead of the script name it logged `undefined` followed by the line number `1`

Comment: @Салман: Of course it works with array objects as well, but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> understand the structure of this object? Is it an array?

That's possible, all properties seem to be numeric. To see your object, just

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```